# Обработка входных данных с помощью функции floatval

Tags: php

При выполнении следующего кода

```
echo floatval("0.000001");
```

Получаем `1.0E-6`. Пожалуйста, подскажите, есть ли решение проблемы?

Comment: [number_format](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php)

Comment: мне при фильтрации данных нужно

Comment: @shogun, вам что нужно, строку с правильным отображением? В этом случае вам нужен `number_format()`. Если вы боитесь, что 1.0Е-6 это какой-то неправильный флоат, то все в порядке, это просто удобное отображение.

Comment: Что мешает при фильтрации данных вызывать `number_format`?

Comment: @shogun, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться. @shogun, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf('%f', floatval("0.000001"));
```